# Superset integration with Keycloak is crashing into an error 500 after username validation

Tags: authentication, flask, keycloak, apache-superset

I've finally managed to get Apache Superset to route user validation to Keycloak, (the keycloak login screen pops up, the KC users are being used and validated and used). Roles to exactly match Superset roles are set in Keycloak, and the Superset URL is correctly defined in the Keycloak client configuration. However, after a user logs in, they get an Error 500 page.

The KC client config has all the SS URL definitions correctly set.[KC Client URL Definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62uTQ.jpg)

The KC roles are set to match SS roles: [KC client roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG9EV.jpg)

and the users are created and have the matching KC roles assigned: [KC user roles details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfBT9.jpg)

The error 500 appears to be a Supeset error 500 (as opossed to a nginx/kc error) from the fonts/graphics displayed.

Inspecting the network trafic from the client side, i get the a call to the superset URL with an oidc_callback reference:

[client network inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSipN.jpg)

and the docker logs show references to an "unknonwn host":

```
superset_app          | 10.30.61.186 - - [10/Aug/2023:14:09:06 +0000] "GET /superset/welcome/ HTTP/1.0" 302 201 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset_app          | 10.30.61.186 - - [10/Aug/2023:14:09:06 +0000] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.0" 302 1449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset_app          | 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2023:14:09:10 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
superset_app          | (504, b'Unknown Host')
superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in full_dispatch_request
superset_app          |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1503, in dispatch_request
superset_app          |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 657, in _oidc_callback
superset_app          |     plainreturn, data = self._process_callback('destination')
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 689, in _process_callback
superset_app          |     credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
superset_app          |     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2053, in step2_exchange
superset_app          |     resp, content = transport.request(
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
superset_app          |     return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1724, in request
superset_app          |     (response, content) = self._request(
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
superset_app          |     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1366, in _conn_request
superset_app          |     conn.connect()
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1156, in connect
superset_app          |     sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 504, in connect
superset_app          |     self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 465, in __negotiatehttp
superset_app          |     raise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
superset_app          | httplib2.socks.HTTPError: (504, b'Unknown Host')
superset_app          | 2023-08-10 14:09:32,111:ERROR:superset.views.base:(504, b'Unknown Host')
```

the authorization handling part of my superset_config.py is:

```
from security import OIDCSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID

logger.info('@keycloak config ..')
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID
curr  =  os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS =  curr + '/docker/pythonpath_dev/client_secret.json'
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE = False
OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL = False
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME = 'pergamino'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
#AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Public'
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = OIDCSecurityManager
```

and my security.py is:

```
from flask import redirect, request, abort
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthOIDView
from flask_login import login_user
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask_appbuilder.views import ModelView, SimpleFormView, expose
import logging
import json
from base64 import b64decode
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()

AFIP_SERVICE_ID = os.environ.get("AFIP_SERVICE_ID", "pergamino")

class AuthOIDCView(AuthOIDView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self, flag=True):
        sm = self.appbuilder.sm
        oidc = sm.oid

        @self.appbuilder.sm.oid.require_login
        def handle_login():
            if not oidc.get_access_token():
                logger.warn('Not found access_token')
                return self.logout()

            roles = findAccessRoles(sm)
            logger.debug('findAccessRoles %s' % roles)

            if not roles or len(roles) == 0:
                logger.warn('Not found roles')
                return self.logout()

            info = oidc.user_getinfo(
                    ['preferred_username', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'email', 'sub'])
            email = oidc.user_getfield('email')
            if email is None:
                logger.debug('email no informado, se intenta crear un valor')
                username = oidc.user_getfield('username') or info.get('preferred_username')
                email = username + "@afip.gob.ar"

            user = sm.auth_user_oid(email)

            if user is None:
                logger.debug('crear usuario %s' % email)
                user = sm.add_user(info.get('preferred_username'), info.get(
                    'given_name'), info.get('family_name'), email, roles[0])

                if len(roles) > 1:
                    user.roles = roles
                    sm.update_user(user)
            elif len(roles) != len(user.roles) or not all(e in roles for e in user.roles):
                logger.debug('actualizar usuario %s' % email)
                user.roles = roles
                sm.update_user(user)

            logger.debug('user.roles %s' % user.roles)

            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
        return handle_login()

    @expose('/logout/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def logout(self):
        oidc = self.appbuilder.sm.oid

        oidc.logout()
        super(AuthOIDCView, self).logout()
        redirect_url = request.url_root.strip(
            '/') + self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login

        return redirect(oidc.client_secrets.get('issuer') + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=' + quote(redirect_url))

class OIDCSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authoidview = AuthOIDCView

    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(OIDCSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
        if self.auth_type == AUTH_OID:
            self.oid = OpenIDConnect(self.appbuilder.get_app)

def findAccessRoles(sm):
    try:
        pre, tkn, post = sm.oid.get_access_token().split('.')
        # logger.debug("get_access_token split . {},{},{}".format(pre, tkn, post))
        if not tkn:
            return None

        idp_token_decode = decode_base64(tkn)
        logger.debug('idp_token_decode %s' % idp_token_decode)
        access_token = json.loads(idp_token_decode)
        logger.debug('access_token in key resource_access.%s.roles' % AFIP_SERVICE_ID)
        rolesAccess = access_token['resource_access'][AFIP_SERVICE_ID]['roles']

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Failed to parser access_token: '+ str(e))
        return None

    logger.debug('rolesAccess %s' % rolesAccess)
    roles = None

    if rolesAccess or len(rolesAccess) > 0:
        roles = []
        for r in rolesAccess:
            find = sm.find_role(r.capitalize())
            if find:
                roles.append(find)
    return roles

def decode_base64(data):
    '''
    FIX -> OIDC + Python3 + Incorrect padding during base64decode
    '''
    missing_padding = 4-len(data) % 4
    if missing_padding:
        data = f"{data}{'=' * missing_padding:}"
    return b64decode(data)
```